# How do I get the particular element instance when an event is registered for multiple elements having same class

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I get the particular element instance when an event is registered for multiple elements having same class?

**Code**

```
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', initBookingHistory); 

function initBookingHistory() 
{ 
    hideJourneyDetails(); 
    ObserveJourneyDetailsForClick(); 
} 

function ObserveJourneyDetailsForClick()
{ 
    $$('.Journey_Details div#Journey_Detail div.head h2 span.wrap').each(function(ele)
    { 
         Event.observe(ele,'click', showOrHideJourneyDetails(ele));
    }) 
} 

function showOrHideJourneyDetails(ele)
{ 
    ele.show(); 
}
```

**Error**

*I get an "Handler is undefined" error*

Comment: Do you want to get the element that invoked an event?

Comment: Added the code that you posted in the comment to the question.

Comment: yes I nee the element that invoked the event

Comment: normally if you have showOrHideJourneyDetails(event) then
event.target or event.currentTarget should have the element you want

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean events like onClick? If that's what you think, you use onclick="do_something(this)"

Comment: Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', initBookingHistory);
function initBookingHistory() {
 hideJourneyDetails();
 ObserveJourneyDetailsForClick();
}
function ObserveJourneyDetailsForClick(){
 $$('.Journey_Details div#Journey_Detail div.head h2 span.wrap').each(function(ele){ Event.observe(ele,'click', showOrHideJourneyDetails(ele));})
}

function showOrHideJourneyDetails(ele){
 ele.show();
}

I get an "Handler is undefined" error for the following code

Comment: Please add this code to your question and make this block code block.